# HA Jenkins in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, high-availability

Firstly - not using docker yet. Jenkins best practice is to have a master and a backup master for fail-over. I've decoupled HOME & mounted it to EFS & backed this up + have got it working in ASG=2. My question is should I Load Balance the 2 nodes, pointing to 1 and then redirecting to backup at fail-over all in ASG=2. Or should I create 2 ASG's one for the master and one for the backup and use AWS DNS Health check to do the repointing. I am keen to have the backup as a lesser speced vm for cost purposes, but am really keen for some clarity to creating HA Jenkins. Iinterested in AWS approach-  not trying to load balance traffic - but create a backup master.

Comment: Also noted that jenkins doesnt like 2 instances pointing to the same efs. Perhaps the jenkins master backup instance should be in an ASG=1 and point to the EFS Backup ??

Comment: Can you tolerate 5 mins of downtime if the instance returns automatically via an ASG ?  In this way you reduce costs and only have one instance active.

Comment: nope - story is all about HA - so need v good uptime, big organisation. seeking suitable HA deployment for jenkins, but next storiess will inc other tooling apps.

Comment: Jenkins does not have a good HA implementation. The best you can get on AWS would be a shared filesystem, with an ASG that will replace lost instances in a few minutes.  For enterprise grade HA consider https://www.cloudbees.com/products. They have specialized plugins for HA

Comment: Cheers - trying to avoid costly Enterprise solutions till more mature. I just wanted to know best way to implement a master and a backup master. Im thinking will investigate route53 DNS Health checking pointing to an ASG=1 and provide failover to a Backup ASG=1 jenkins instance and see how that works - was curious how others have done this without cloudbees.. Curently have it in  an ASG=1 for this sprint maybe look to alter if and when demand increases - cheers for info

Comment: Yes understood.  We live with the single instance and an ASG with shared files.   Small HA/uptime hit, but its easy to manage. We are a small company.

Answer (score 1):

ASG = 1 itself is HA. 
If you want zero downtime, configure 2 Jenkins(1 per AZ) behind an ALB. Backup only Jenkins config directory to save money. There is S3 plugin available for that.

For a detailed answer go through this paper. Check out the DR and HA part.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/jenkins-on-aws/jenkins-on-aws.pdf